# How to send id parameter based on which button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Demo and full code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/o5qn5gum/8/

My HTML code is like this :

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>

<div id="tes">

</div>


<!-- Modal Currency-->
<div class="modal fade" id="priceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">


            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                //type: 'POST',
                //url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    var isitable = '';
                    isitable += '<br><button class="btn btn-primary tes" id="NationCd=ID&CityCd=JKT">Book 1</button><br><br>';
                    isitable += '<button class="btn btn-primary test" id="NationCd=ID&CityCd=BAI">Book 2</button><br><br>';
                    isitable += '<button class="btn btn-primary test" id="NationCd=ID&CityCd=JOG">Book 3</button><br>';

                    // console.log(isitable);
                    $("#tes").html(isitable);                   
                }
            });
        });

        $(".test").click(function(){
            console.log('tes');
            var id = this.id;
            console.log(id);
        });
    });
```

When click button "Click me", It will display three button. Look jsfidde.

When click the button (for example, I click button "book 1"), It will send parameter id.  I do `console.log(this.id);` in `$(".test").click(function(){`, but it's not working.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do an AJAX call, you have to put your click event in the `success` part like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      //type: 'POST',
      //url: 'script.php',
      success: function(data) {
        var isitable = '';
        isitable += '<br><button class="btn btn-primary test" id="NationCd=ID&CityCd=JKT">Book 1</button><br><br>';
        isitable += '<button class="btn btn-primary test" id="NationCd=ID&CityCd=BAI">Book 2</button><br><br>';
        isitable += '<button class="btn btn-primary test" id="NationCd=ID&CityCd=JOG">Book 3</button><br>';

        // console.log(isitable);
        $("#tes").html(isitable);
        $(".test").click(function(){
          console.log('tes');
          var id = this.id;
          console.log(id);
        });

      }
    });
  });


});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5qn5gum/10/)

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280802/how-to-change-amcharts-pie-themes